# Как обрезать(достать) первые 4 цифры из строки

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть строка БИН к примеру '`582100276617`' и мне нужно первые 4 цифры т.е `5821`

И из текущий даты нужно обрезать год и месяц: например `2016.11.24` отсюда нужно `'1611'`
Попробовал: `var bin = iinbin.Substring(0, 3);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var linbin = "582100276617";
var bin = linbin.Substring(0, 4);
Console.WriteLine(bin);

var lindate = "2016.11.24";
var date = lindate.Substring(2, 2) + lindate.Substring(5, 2);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Для варианта с типом Date

```
var lindate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
var date = lindate.Substring(8, 2) + lindate.Substring(3, 2);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Comment: С типом Date все делается намного проще! `.ToString("yyMM")` - и не надо никаких вырезаний подстрок.

Comment: @PavelMayorov круто, не знал